# Python - unable to count occurences of values in defined ranges in dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to write a code that takes analyses values in a dataframe, if the values fall in a class, the total number of those values are assigned to a key in the dictionary. But the code is not working for me.  Im trying to create logarithmic classes and count the total number of values that fall in it

```
def bins(df):  
"""Returns new df with values assigned to bins"""  
bins_dict = {500: 0, 5000: 0, 50000: 0, 500000: 0}  
for i in df:  
    if 100<i and i<=1000:  
            bins_dict[500]+=1,  
    elif 1000<i and i<=10000:  
            bins_dict[5000]+=1  
print(bins_dict)
```

However, this is returning the original dictionary.

I've also tried modifying the dataframe using

```
def transform(df, range):   
for i in df:  
    for j in range:  
        b=10**j  
        while j==1:  
            while i>100:  
                if i>=b:  
                    j+=1,  
                elif i<b:  
                    b = b/2,  
                    print (i = b*(int(i/b)))
```

This code is returning the original dataframe.

My dataframe consists of only one column with values ranging between 100 and 10000000

```
Data Sample:  
    Area  
0   1815  
1   907  
2   1815  
3   907  
4   907
```

Expected output

`dict={500:3, 5000:2, 50000:0}`

If i can get a dataframe output directly that would be helpful too
PS. I am very new to programming and I only know python

Comment: provide data sample and your expected output.

Comment: I have updated the post with the same

Comment: if Area column has value less than 500, what should it return?

Comment: so the aim is to get all values between 100 and 1000 to be counted as an occurence against 500, values between 1000 and 10000 against 5000, and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use pandas for it:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['Area'] = [1815, 907, 1815, 907, 907]

# create new column to categorize your data
df['bins'] = pd.cut(df['Area'], [0,1000,10000,100000], labels=['500', '5000', '50000'])

# converting into dictionary 
dic = dict(df['bins'].value_counts())

print(dic)
```

Output:

```
{'500': 3, '5000': 2, '50000': 0}
```